# How to update label on tick event

Tags: c#-4.0

I have a web form in which i want to show timing label for user,like 180 second,
i have done using following code,

```
<div>
        <asp:ScriptManager ID="SM1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
        <asp:Timer ID="timer1" runat="server" Interval="1000"
            OnTick="timer1_tick">
        </asp:Timer>
    </div>
    <div>
        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="updPnl" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
            <ContentTemplate>
                <asp:Label  ID="lblTimer" runat="server"></asp:Label>
            </ContentTemplate>
            <Triggers>
                <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="timer1" EventName="tick" />
            </Triggers>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
    </div>
```

and code behind

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            if (!Page.IsPostBack)
            {
                Page.Header.Title = "Test";

            }
            if (!SM1.IsInAsyncPostBack)
                Session["TimeCount"] = DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(180).ToString();
        }
```

and

```
 protected void timer1_tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (0 > DateTime.Compare(DateTime.Now,
            DateTime.Parse(Session["TimeCount"].ToString())))
            {
                lblTimer.Text = "Number of Second Left: " +
                ((Int32)DateTime.Parse(Session["TimeCount"].
                ToString()).Subtract(DateTime.Now).TotalSeconds).ToString();
            }
            else
            {

            }
        }
```

problem i am facing that each time user click on button in page counter refresh to 180 again,Secondly this show fix value like 177,170,i want to show that label auto decreasing ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Update label on tick Event in web form](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35840297/how-to-update-label-on-tick-event-in-web-form)

Comment: yes ,i tried first with question,now this updated