# How to Update label on tick Event in web form

Tags: c#-4.0

I have a web form in which i want to show label with time in decreasing fashion from 180 second to zero,i am using following code.

```
<div>
        <asp:ScriptManager ID="SM1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
        <asp:Timer ID="timer1" runat="server" Interval="1000"
            OnTick="timer1_tick">
        </asp:Timer>
    </div>
    <div>
        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="updPnl" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
            <ContentTemplate>
                <asp:Label  ID="lblTimer" runat="server"></asp:Label>
            </ContentTemplate>
            <Triggers>
                <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="timer1" EventName="tick" />
            </Triggers>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
    </div>
```

and code behind

```
protected void timer1_tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (0 > DateTime.Compare(DateTime.Now,
            DateTime.Parse(Session["TimeCount"].ToString())))
            {
                lblTimer.Text = "Number of Second Left: " +
                ((Int32)DateTime.Parse(Session["TimeCount"].
                ToString()).Subtract(DateTime.Now).TotalSeconds).ToString();
            }
            else
            {

            }
        }
```

and page load

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

```
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            Page.Header.Title = "Test";
            NewRecord();
        }
        if (!SM1.IsInAsyncPostBack)
            Session["TimeCount"] = DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(180).ToString();
    }
```

problem is that counter refresh each time to 180 when user click on button,and label is static value like 177,173 etc,i want to show changing in counting is shown to user?it is basically Q/A software.

Comment: Please don't post duplicate questions - instead, edit your question as needed to add detail.

Comment: ok ,next time i b carefull